# Как закрыть activity по названию?

Tags: android, activity

У меня есть activity
A-B-C-D-E

Мне нужно закрыть activity CDE когда пользователь перешел из E в B. Тобишь пользователь открывает C D E после переходит в B и в этот момент нужно закрыть CDE.

Должны остаться A B.
Если пользовател в C или в D то ничего закрывать не нужно

P.S. Прочитал свой вопрос и вспомнил задачки по информатике))

Comment: Активити не нужно специально закрывать, они сделают это сами, когда система посчитает это необходимым. Может вам нужно очистить стек переходов, чтобы из В по "назад" не вернуться в Е? или какая цель этих закрытий

Comment: @pavlofff, Да но хотелось бы чтобы A не закрылось. Ведь если очистить стек. то и Activity A удалиться...

Comment: На самом деле можно, но у вас в вопросе нет точности перехода. То что вы хотите сделать, делается вызовом массивов activities и флагом сингл топ, а дальше нужно смотреть каждый случай по отдельности.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если пользователь переходит "из Е в В", то это значит, что B запускается Intent'ом. Добавьте флаг [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP):

```
Intent a = new Intent(this, B.class);
a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(a);
```

> For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D. If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.

Сразу обратите внимание, что новый интент придет в onNewIntent(), а getIntent() будет возвращать интент, которым активити была запущена первый раз.

Comment: Вы тему читали вообще? я же писал что такой подход не подойдет ибо он стирает Активити A!!

Comment: Не стирает. Добавил цитату из документации, она полностью соответствует вопросу. Вы, вероятно, путаете с FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.